# Arrange the columns based on count of values

Tags: r, sorting

```
Input:

Sample  Name2    Name5    Name4   Name8   Name1   group
 ERT    0.111    0.389    0.378     0       1       HJ
 KLJ       0     0.167      1     0.875   0.389     HJ
 FGT    0.867    0.4345    0.4      0     0.487     KO
 SDF   0.99234     0      0.98    0.007   0.786     KO
 JHU    0.3347     0        0       0        1      FR
```

I need to order the columns based on the count of values >=0.3. For e.g: In the column "Name2" I see the count of values >=0.3 are 3. For other columns "Name5" - 2, "Name4" - 4, "Name8" - 1, "Name1" - 5. Based on this count I need to arrange the columns in decreasing order and output should look like following:

```
Output:

Sample   Name8    Name5    Name2   Name4     Name1   group
 ERT       0      0.389    0.111   0.378       1       HJ
 KLJ    0.875     0.167      0       1       0.389     HJ
 FGT       0      0.4345   0.867     0.4     0.487     KO
 SDF    0.007       0      0.99234  0.98     0.786     KO
 JHU       0        0      0.3347    0         1       FR
```

Comment: This is like Deja Vu!

Comment: Nope there its is not ordering the columns. There it is ordering of values. Just check my input and output clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `colSums` to count values above a threshold and use `order` to get the order of columns based on the count:

```
df[c(1, order(colSums(df[-1] >= 0.3)) + 1)]

#  Sample Name8  Name5   Name2 Name4 Name1
#1    ERT 0.000 0.3890 0.11100 0.378 1.000
#2    KLJ 0.875 0.1670 0.00000 1.000 0.389
#3    FGT 0.000 0.4345 0.86700 0.400 0.487
#4    SDF 0.007 0.0000 0.99234 0.980 0.786
#5    JHU 0.000 0.0000 0.33470 0.000 1.000
```

Comment: Thankyou...Could you please tell me what is 1 in the starting of the command and +1 in end of the command?

Comment: The 1 in the beginning is to include the first column in the result, as it has been dropped when rank the columns; The +1 at the end is to shift the order to the right by one so that they will pick up the correct columns.